# Toggling layers with arcgis javascript api 3.5

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using the two reference samples in the api, [toggle](http://help.arcgis.com/en/webapi/javascript/arcgis/jssamples/map_explicitlayerlist.html) and [dynamic toggle](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/map_dynamiclayerlist.html).  I tried to use the method in the basic toggle but the setvisbiblelayers doesn't seem to like my kml layers and I get a javascript error

```
Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'setVisibleLayers'
```

Here is where I add my basemap and kml layers.

```js
            dojo.require("esri.map");
            dojo.require("esri.layers.KMLLayer");

            var layer, map, visible = [];

            function init() {
              var beginExt = new esri.geometry.Extent(-81.26, 40.64, -74.10, 42.29, new esri.SpatialReference({wkid:4326}));
              var revExt = esri.geometry.geographicToWebMercator(beginExt);
              var imageParameters = new esri.layers.ImageParameters();
              imageParameters.layerIds = ['base'];
              imageParameters.layerOption = esri.layers.ImageParameters.LAYER_OPTION_SHOW;

              map = new esri.Map("map",{
                basemap:"topo",
                extent:revExt,
                sliderStyle:"small"
              });


              var kml10url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/...kmz file";
              var hospital2010kml = new esri.layers.KMLLayer(kml10url, {id:"hospital2010kml"});
              var kml00url = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/...kmz file";
              var hospital2000kml = new esri.layers.KMLLayer(kml00url, {id:"hospital2000kml"});
              map.addLayer(hospital2010kml);
              map.addLayer(hospital2000kml);
```

This works fine.  I am able to see both of the layers and the basemap.  However when I try to toggle between the layers nothing.  So I tried this, which used to work in 2.6 but no longer works in 3.5.

```js
  function updateLayerVisibility() {
                var inputs = dojo.query(".list_item"), input;

                for (var i=0, il=inputs.length; i<il; i++) {
                    if (inputs[i].checked) {
                        console.log("Input Length " +inputs.length);
                        console.log("Inputs in checked " +inputs[i]);
                        if('hospital2010kml' === inputs[i].id)
                        {
                            console.log('Showing hospital2010kml visibility');
                            hospital2010kml.show();
                        }
                        else if('hospital2000kml' === inputs[i].id)
                        {
                            console.log('Showing hospital2000kml visibility');
                            hospital2000kml.show();
                        }
                    console.log(inputs[i].id);  
                    }
                    else{
                        console.log("Input Length Hide " +inputs.length);
                        console.log("Inputs in checked Hide " +inputs[i]);
                        if('hospital2010kml' === inputs[i].id)
                        {
                            console.log('Hiding hospital2010kml visibility');
                            hospital2010kml.hide();
                        }
                        else if('hospital2000kml' === inputs[i].id)
                        {
                            console.log('Hiding hospital2000kml visibility');
                            hospital2000kml.hide();
                        }
                    }
                }
```

This then gives the error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'hide'

It gives an error for show as well.  Anybody know how to toggle two separate kml layers?  The API says there is a show and hide for kmllayers so I don't know what is up?

Comment: Just before calling .show() or .hide(), try inspecting the layer objects themselves by calling console.log(hospital2010kml); -- the object will show up in the developer console and you can inspect its properties/methods etc. If it's a valid KMLLayer object, it should have show/hide methods, as you said.

Comment: @greenlaw thanks for the tip.  So apparently there is something wrong with it because it just comes back as [object HTMLInputElement].  On my 2.6 API version it shows up fine.  So something up with 3.5 that doesn't like me code.  Hmmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was I did not have my kml variables defined outside the init function so when it got to the update layers function it didn't know it was a kml layer.  For some reason when I logged the id to console it worked but it was just generic object hence the no show hide commands.  I added the declaration outside the init as follows:

```
var layer, map, hospital2000kml, hospital2010kml, visible = [];
```

Now it is working... Wow I wasted a lot of time on something I should have caught hours ago.